# OAuth in ADFS: how can I get user's personal data

Tags: php, oauth, adfs

I'm trying to add login with ADFS through OAuth protocol in my (PHP) app. It's easy to obtain access token (described e.g. [here](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Authorization-Code-grant-in-ADFS)), but it's not clear how can I get users personal data. Is it possible? And how if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd found an answer to my question. One can get personal data (claims) from `access_code` (it's in JWT format).

```
$jwt_arr = explode('.', $access_token);
$jwt_decoded = base64_decode($jwt_arr[1]);
```

`$jwt_decoded` is json object (serialized to string) containing data

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about ADFS 3.0?

The UserInfo endpoint in OpenID Connect is normally used for this but ADFS 3.0 doesn't support OpenID Connect.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ADFS 3.0.

Comment: So, you are trying to say that it's impossible to get user data in my case? But what was the aim of adding OAuth to ADFS then?

Comment: To support Web API only.